# Contract Violation

Tags: algorithm, scheme, racket, r5rs

I am trying to write a recursive function to test if the digits in the integer entered are in ascending order. When I run my code I get a contract violation error.

```
(define (rising-numbers n)
  (if(zero? (truncate n))
     (modulo n 10)
     (> (modulo n 10) (rising-numbers (quotient n 10)))))

(rising-numbers 123)
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
>: contract violation
expected: real?
given: #t
argument position: 2nd
other arguments...:
```

Comment: Here's a small expression that raises the same error: `(> 2 #true)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your function I see that you function returns **a number** when `(zero? (truncate n))` and a **boolean** if it's false. The reason for that is the fact that  `>` always return a boolean `#t` or `#f`.  While returning different types is a feature of the language it's usually an error when it gets unpredictable in runtime.

According to the error message you have given a boolean value as one of the arguments to `>`. So the problem lies in the only place you use `>`:

```
(> (modulo n 10) (rising-numbers (quotient n 10)))
```

Here you do `(rising-numbers (quotient n 10))` as a numeric argument but since we already established in the first section this can return a boolean you cannot use this value as the second argument  in `>`.

So how do you do it right. Well. As always we have the base case:

```
(rising-numbers 2); ==> #t
```

Now the default case should do this:

```
(rising-numbers 123)                             ; ==
(and (<= 2 3) (rising-numbers 12))               ; ==
(and (<= 2 3) (and (<= 1 2) (rising-numbers 1))) ; ==
(and #t #t)                                      ; ==> #t
```

In this case `rising-numbers` never returns numbers, always booleans, and you need to check the current and next value in each step. In fact you get one base case and n-1 comparison between current and next digit.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a *perfect* one for the stepper. Make sure the language level is "Beginning Student", put nothing other than the code you pasted in the definitions window, and click "step". I think you'll see the problem pretty quickly!